# REST - Add Recipient to Envelope Role

Tags: docusignapi

I am attempting to add recipients to a draft envelope that was created from a Template that uses to roles ('AlliancesDirectoy' & 'Partner'). Both Roles are in routing order 1 for clarity but that shouldn't matter.

After creating the envelope we can see the draft envelope has been created with two defined roles.

[image]

Now i attempt to add a recipient to my role 'AlliancesDirector'.

```
{
    "signers": [
    {
      "email": "mike@xyz.com",
      "Name": "Mike",
      "RecipientId": 1,
      "RoleName": "AlliancesDirector",
    }
  ]
}
```

Which results in the following response:
[image]

If i then look at the recipients that are already added to the envelope id see the following:
[image]

Naturally this leads me to believe it doesn't like when i try to add a recipient using the already in use recipientId of '1'.  If I change the recipientId to 5, for example, it adds my recipient **in addition to the role**. I don't want to add in addition to the role, i want to put a user into the pre-defined role.

Hope this more detailed explanation of what i'm trying to accomplish helps.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are passing valid JSON with the extra comma in `"RoleName": "AlliancesDirector",`.  You're also not using regular cammelCase... it should be `roleName`, `recipientId`, etc.  And what URL and method are you using for each of the 2 calls?

Comment: You should also include the request body you're using when you create the envelope from the template in the first place.

Comment: The more I think about this the problem must be with how you are creating the envelope from a template.  Do you assign the recipients to the roles at that point?  What's your JSON look like for that call??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some time to crack this but was finally able to reproduce your error and I believe I know what you're doing wrong.  In line with my questions about the details of the 2nd API call you are making, you need to do a [Recipient Correction](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Modify%20or%20Correct%20and%20Resend%20Recipient%20Information.htm) to assign the recipient to a given template role, and I was getting the same error you were when I was mistakenly using the `POST` method and think you are doing the same.

Change your 2nd call from a `POST` to a `PUT` and it should work.  I've verified in my testing that this is working as expected.

Comment: That's it exactly.  It hand't occurred to me to perform a PUT but it does make sense now given the existing recipientId in play that needs updating.  I haven't been around much since you guys moved forum locations but great work as always.

One additional quick question:  Is it safe to assume only one user can occupy a template role or is there a way to add multiple users to a role?

Answer (score 1):

This would be to add a recipient to a template upon creation of the envelope.

```
{
    "emailSubject": "StackOverflow Test",
    "status": "created",
    "templateId": "63611019-753f-41c2-b9fe-6aab8ea26387",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "so@emaildomain.com",
            "name": "Stack Overflow",
            "roleName": "Leet Person"
        }
    ]
}
```

This would be to add a recipient to an existing envelope (regardless on if it's a template or not):

```
{
    "signers": [
        {
            "name": "Stack Overflow",
            "email": "so@emaildomain.com",
            "roleName": "Leet Person",
            "recipientId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

As always please refer to the documentation [Here](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) for specific guidance with calls.

### Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient Information

This lets you modify recipients in a draft envelope or correct recipient information for an in process envelope.

For draft envelopes, you can edit: email, userName, routingOrder, faxNumber, deliveryMethod, 
accessCode and requireIdLookup.

---

**Note:** If you send information for a recipient that does not already exist in a draft envelope, the 
recipient will be added to the envelope (similar to the POST).

---

Once an envelope has been sent, you can only edit: email, userName, signerName, routingOrder, 
faxNumber, and deliveryMethod. You can also select to resend an envelope by using the 
resend_envelope option.

**URL:**

`/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients`

Optional addition: `resend_envelope` {true or false}

Comment: Thank you but i find two problems with the second json string.
1. RecipientId is already taken by the roles originally specified by the template. In your case RecipientId '1' would not be valid because it's in use.
2. If I increase recipientId to say 10 (a number not taken by a role) then it adds the new 'Signer' in this case, in addition to the role.  Is this not what you find?

Comment: You have to find the recipientId from the role you're trying to update and use that. my example was a very simplistic one since you didn't provide much more than a simple question :)